# Will all objects created inline in a `using` statement be disposed of?

Tags: c#, dispose, using

This may be answered elsewhere, but after doing a bit of searching I didn't find much on the subject outside of the normal `using` context.

I am curious if *all* objects created in a `using` block will be disposed of as well as the original object.

**Here is the context:**

*Normally* I would do something like this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
{
    //Do everything I need to here
}
```

I know that both `conn` and `cmd` go out of scope at this point and are disposed of because of the lovely `using` keyword.

I am curious if the same disposal rules would apply to the following statement:

```
using (var cmd = new (SqlCommand(commandText, new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)))
{
   //Do everything I need here
}
```

Would the `SqlConnection` object that was created inline in the `using` statment be disposed of when `cmd` goes out of scope and is disposed of because it's associated with the object?

Also which would be syntactically preferred?  I personally think the 2nd is cleaner, but I understand readability may come to play here as well.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini Bah, I had a feeling this might already exist, just couldn't find the right search term to pull it up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your second code, `Dispose` won't be called on `SqlConnection` instance when flow leaves `using` block unless `SqlCommand.Dispose()` do that internally (and no, it doesn't).

According to specification (8.13), `using (ResourceType resource = expression) statement` is transformed into:

```
{
    ResourceType resource = expression;
    try {
        statement;
    }
    finally {
        if(resource != null)
            ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
    }
}
```

In your code, `resource` is `SqlCommand`, and that's the one `Dispose` is called on.

Comment: Okay, so then this would not be the preferred way to handle this?  Or is there a way to actually dispose of the associated `SqlConnection` in this case?

Comment: "unless SqlCommand.Dispose() do that internally" -- It doesn't do that internally.

Comment: @EvanL Use two `using` blocks, like in your first code.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that was the case (my instinct kept telling me "don't do it!")  So thought I would ask =)

Answer (score 4):

No.

`using` statements only apply to the resources declared directly in the statement; not to other allocations in the initializer.

You need a separate `using` statement for each resource.

Answer (score 2):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), this code:

```
using (var temp = obj)
{
    // ...
}
```

Translates to (including the extra curly braces to limit the scope):

```
{
    var temp = obj;
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    finally
    {
        if (temp != null)
            ((IDisposable)temp).Dispose();
    }
}
```

As you can see, if you substitute `obj` for `new SqlCommand(commandText, new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))` then only the `SqlCommand` gets properly disposed.

```
{
    SqlCommand temp = new SqlCommand(commandText,
        new SqlConnection(ConnectionString));
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    finally
    {
        if (temp != null)
            ((IDisposable)temp).Dispose();
    }
}
```

So, the `SqlConnection` won't get disposed unless the disposed `SqlCommand` does that. But it doesn't, and it shouldn't: it didn't create the object, therefore it must not destroy it either.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly there are already answers that explains this correctly. This is covered by the specification as mentioned by others.

But you could just try it out. Here is an example:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (new DisposeMe("outer", new DisposeMe("inner", null)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside using");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("after using scope");
    }
}

class DisposeMe : IDisposable
{
    public readonly string name;

    public DisposeMe(string name, object dummy)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'Dispose' was called on instance named " + name);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
inside using
'Dispose' was called on instance named outer
after using scope
```

(Of course if you nest two `using` statements, as in `using (var inner = new DisposeMe("inner", null))
            {
                using (new DisposeMe("outer", inner))
                { ... } }`, the `Dispose` method is called on both objects.)